# What suggestions for a 3d game engine to support a huge terrain?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

There are a lot of 3d game engines around, does anyone with experience with them have advice on which one would likely be able to handle these (arbitrary) requirements?

- opengl
- mac/pc
- 1000x1000km terrain
- 1000 towns varying in size from 10
  to 1000 buildings
- 128 people in any one location
- MMO type networking (no solo play)
- physics engine including airfoil (ie airplanes)
- c++ with optional scripting

Comment: I dont think youre going to find an engine whose physics are so good that they support airfoil activity.  Doesn't that imply air existing and having pressures and velocities?  Thats going to magnify any cpu requirements beyond what a realtime engine could do.  You can fake a plane easily enough.

Comment: Good luck with that - perhaps you could add 'Must provide Moon on Stick' to your list of requirements?

Comment: Well I work on an old engine for an existing MMO which does these things but it's pretty old (11 yrs) and it would be nice to see what's possible on an exiting commercial or opensource engine.

Comment: Asking on reddit got me suggestions for Unity3D and UnrealT3 as well, but neither is quite all there either. I guess there is no real answer without experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/). It supports OpenGL/DirectX, Mac/Linux/Windows, written in C++. But it is not game engine, it is 3D rendering engine. You can integrate other networking/physics engines with Ogre.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest the Torque Game Engine.  Some of the things you're asking for aren't really possible (as others have pointed out), but are problems that have to be tackled in a round about way (like faking the airfoil physics). The Torque engine would be a good starting place for you. There's also a 2D version called Torque Game Builder which might be easier to start with.

[www.garagegames.com](http://www.garagegames.com)

Answer (score 0):

A plug for [openscenegraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org), has all of that plus paeed terrains, level of detail LOD  etc - it's used by  [flightgear](http://www.flightgear.org) flight simulator as well as a lot of commercial and military simulators